# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'experience'). after all this i should get profile with all experience .but all time i end up with server err

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**i was following brad traversy's one of his udemy course. after working on adding experience in profile in profile routes. i all time get server error. but it should end up with full profile details like in brad course.**  this is my github link for that project

https://github.com/arshad007hossain/findDevs

**profile.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require("../../middleware/authmiddleware");
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const Profile = require("../../models/Profile");
const User = require("../../models/User");

// @route    GET api/profile/me
// @desc     Get current users profile
// @access   Private
router.get("/me", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const profile = await Profile.findOne({
      user: req.user.id,
    }).populate("user", ["name", "avatar"]);

    if (!profile) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "There is no profile for this user" });
    }

    res.json(profile);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});

// @route    POST api/profile/me
// @desc     create or update users profile
// @access   Private

router.post(
  "/",
  [
    auth,
    [
      check("status", "status is required").not().isEmpty(),
      check("skills", "skills is required").not().isEmpty(),
    ],
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const {
      company,
      website,
      location,
      bio,
      status,
      githubusername,
      facebook,
      linkedin,
      twitter,
      instagram,
      youtube,
      skills,
    } = req.body;

    //build user profile

    const profileFields = {};
    profileFields.user = req.user.id;
    if (company) profileFields.company = company;
    if (website) profileFields.website = website;
    if (location) profileFields.location = location;
    if (bio) profileFields.bio = bio;
    if (status) profileFields.status = company;
    if (githubusername) profileFields.githubusername = githubusername;
    if (skills) {
      profileFields.skills = skills.split(",").map((skill) => skill.trim());
    }

    //build social objects

    profileFields.social = {};

    if (youtube) profileFields.social.youtube = youtube;
    if (twitter) profileFields.social.twitter = twitter;
    if (linkedin) profileFields.social.linkedin = linkedin;
    if (instagram) profileFields.social.instagram = instagram;
    if (facebook) profileFields.social.facebook = facebook;

    //console.log(profileFields.skills);
    try {
      let profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

      if (profile) {
        //Update
        profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
          { user: req.user.id },
          { $set: profileFields },
          { new: true }
        );
        return res.json(profile);
      }

      //create
      profile = new Profile(profileFields);
      await profile.save();

      res.json(profile);
    } catch (err) {
      console.errora(err.message);
      res.status(500).json("server error");
    }
  }
);

// @route    GET api/profile
// @desc     Get all profile
// @access   Public

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let profiles = await Profile.find().populate("user", ["name", "avatar"]);
    res.json(profiles);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).json("server error");
  }
});
// @route    GET api/profile/user/user_id
// @desc     Get single profile
// @access   Public

router.get("/user/:user_id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const profile = await Profile.findOne({
      user: req.params.user_id,
    }).populate("user", ["name", "avatar"]);
    if (!profile) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Profile not found" });
    res.json(profile);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.kind == "ObjectId") {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Profile not found" });
    }
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).json("server error");
  }
});

// @route    DELETE api/profile
// @desc     Delete profile, user
// @access   Private
router.delete("/", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Remove profile
    await Profile.findOneAndRemove({ user: req.user.id });
    // Remove user
    await User.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.user.id });
    res.json({ msg: "User deleted" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});

// @route    PUT api/profile/experience
// @desc     Add profile experience
// @access   Private
router.put(
  '/experience',
  [
    auth,
    [
      check('title', 'Title is required field').not().isEmpty(),
      check('company', 'Company is required field').not().isEmpty(),
      check('from', 'From date is required field').not().isEmpty(),
    ],
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    const {
      title,
      company,
      location,
      from,
      to,
      current,
      description,
    } = req.body;

    const newExp = {
      title,
      company,
      location,
      from,
      to,
      current,
      description,
    };
    try {
      const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });
      profile.experience.unshift(newExp);
      await profile.save();
      res.json(profile);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  });

module.exports = router;
```

**User.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

**Profile.js Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  },
  company: {
    type: String
  },
  website: {
    type: String
  },
  location: {
    type: String
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  skills: {
    type: [String],
    required: true
  },
  bio: {
    type: String
  },
  githubusername: {
    type: String
  },
  experience: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      company: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      location: {
        type: String
      },
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      to: {
        type: Date
      },
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      description: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ],
  education: [
    {
      school: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      degree: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      fieldofstudy: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      to: {
        type: Date
      },
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      description: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ],
  social: {
    youtube: {
      type: String
    },
    twitter: {
      type: String
    },
    facebook: {
      type: String
    },
    linkedin: {
      type: String
    },
    instagram: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('profile', ProfileSchema);
```

Comment: I'm guessing `profile.experience.unshift(newExp);` is causing the error.  Perhaps if you send `profile` to the console when there's an error, the problem will become apparent.

Comment: i can't understand this.are u saying to console the profile

Comment: Currently in your `catch`, you log/print/show _no_ data.  Wouldn't it be nice to know what `profile` is when `profile.experience.unshift(newExp);` generates an error?

Comment: I can't figured it out myself.will u look at my github link

Comment: Your code doesn't handle the possibility that `profile.experience` doesn't exist in all documents.  I'm guessing that the doc that generates the error doesn't have it, or     it's not what you expect.  GitHub doesn't show any data so there's nothing for me to look at, data-wise.  Also, please see my comment for one of your commits on GitHub.